# Error-correcting codes based on Galois fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois

I seem to recall reading that some French mathematician (perhaps a member of Bourbaki?) came up with the idea of basing error-correcting codes on Galois fields quite early in the development of algebraic coding theory, but I don’t remember the details, and my googling skills haven’t helped me come up with any leads.

Golay’s original 1949 article on what are now called Golay codes does not mention finite fields. On the other hand, the 1959 article of Bose and Ray-Chaudhuri on what are now called BCH codes does. So in between 1949 and 1959 someone must have noticed the connection between codes and finite fields. Was it Alexis Hocqueghem, John Cocke, or someone else?

(Apologies to those who posted the first few comments that appear below for not crafting my original post with more care. If those comments are now hard for others to interpret it is because I’ve fixed the wording of the question to address their concerns.)

Comment: What are "Galois codes"? Are you talking about [Golay codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue_code) over Galois fields?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer. I’ll clarify in the main post.

Comment: The mathematician is [Marcel Golay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcel_J._E._Golay), he was Swiss rather than French and not related to Bourbaki. He introduced Galois fields' based binary and ternary  error-correcting codes in 1949 (now called Golay codes). A good source on the early history of error-correcting codes that goes deep into Golay's work and much else is [Thompson, From Error-Correcting Codes Through Sphere Packings to Simple Groups](https://maa.org/press/maa-reviews/from-error-correcting-codes-through-sphere-packings-to-simple-groups).

Comment: I looked at Golay’s original paper (https://web.archive.org/web/20161007122006/http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~ybazlov/code/golay_paper.pdf) but it doesn’t mention finite fields. I’ll look at Thompson’s book to see if he identifies the source of the insight relating error-correcting codes to finite fields.

Comment: [BCH codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BCH_code) are error-correcting codes that use polynomials over finite fields (Galois fields).  They were introduced by [Alexis Hocquenghem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexis_Hocquenghem) in 1959.

Comment: I’ve got a copy of Thompson’s book now. The Galois fields $GF(p^m)$ don’t get mentioned by Thompson until page 44. He stresses that Golay didn’t know about them in 1949 and that John Cocke used them to construct codes in 1959 but he doesn’t say what happened in between or who first noticed that the cyclic shift in the construction of the code could be viewed as multiplication. Was it Hocquenghem? (Thompson doesn’t mention him at all.)

Comment: The article of Bose and Ray-Chaudhuri uses finite fields explicitly. I haven’t found an online copy of Hocquenghem’s paper yet, so I can’t say if it does too.

Comment: @nwr: I've now looked at Hocquenghem's article, and the only field it mentions is "le corps de caracteristique 2" (by which he means the field with 2 elements, though of course there are infinitely many fields of characteristic 2). He constructs BCH codes using irreducible polynomials over the 2-element field, but it's not clear to me that he knew about finite fields. Am I missing something? See https://jamespropp.org/hocquenghem.pdf (a copy of Hocquenghem's article).

Comment: @JamesPropp Sorry, I can't help you any further here.  It's not an area that I'm overly familiar with.  Also note that your link to jamespropp.org is not working - it times out each time I request it.

Comment: Try https://faculty.uml.edu/jpropp/hocquenghem.pdf ; it should be more responsive.

Comment: Have you considered writing to Neil Sloane?  The bible on error-correcting codes was written by MacWilliams and Sloane, so I imagine he would be a great source on the development of the subject!